# How to allow Text to grow enough to display entire contents without truncation?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create a SwiftUI view that represents a chat conversation in a series of vertically arranged bubbles, like in Messages.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to display very long messages. I would like to display such messages simply as very large bubbles that display all of the text. For example, like Messages does this:

[image: Example of what I'd like a long message to look like]

The problem I run into is that the Text view, on which my bubbles are based, pretty much does its own thing. This can lead to the entire text being displayed correctly for small messages, long messages being broken into several lines but still displayed in full, other long messages being reduced to a single line with an ellipse.

Consider the following code to create a sequence of messages:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a very long message. Can you imagine it will ever be displayed in full on the screen? Because I can‘t. I can tell you, the one other time I wrote a message this long was when we went to the picnic and uncle Bob whipped out his cigars and I had to vent on the family WhatsApp group.")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { i in
                MessageView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

It results in this undesirable layout:

[image: A VStack of 100 Text views with lengthy contents]

I have experimented with `fixedSize` and `frame` after reading several SwiftUI guides; this makes it possible to make bubbles large, but then they have a fixed size and/or won't grow when the text to display is even longer than expected.

How can I tell the MessageViews – or rather the Text views inside them – that they're free to take up as much space as they need vertically to render their text contents in full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one interesting decision, using List and removing dividers:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().tableFooterView = UIView()
        UITableView.appearance().separatorStyle = .none
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { i in
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {

                    if i%2 == 0 {
                        MessageView().lineLimit(nil)
                    } else {
                        MessageViewLeft()
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I made 2 structs, for demonstration:

```
struct MessageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("This is a very long message. Can you imagine it will ever be displayed in full on the screen? Because I can‘t. I can tell you, the one other time I wrote a message this long was when we went to the picnic and uncle Bob whipped out his cigars and I had to vent on the family WhatsApp group.")
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
        }
    }
}

struct MessageViewLeft: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            Text("This is a very long message. Can you imagine it will ever be displayed in full on the screen? Because I can‘t. I can tell you, the one other time I wrote a message this long was when we went to the picnic and uncle Bob whipped out his cigars and I had to vent on the family WhatsApp group.")
        }
    }
}
```

the result is:
[image]

P.S. the answer should be **.lineLimit(nil)**, but there is some bug with this in TextField. Maybe with Text this bug continues too

P.P.S. I wad hastened with the answer =(. You can set your VStack List into ScrollView:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { i in
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {
                        MessageView().padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the result is:
[image]

Comment: The key point was to use either a ScrollView or a List instead of the VStack to hold the MessageViews. I assume this is because the VStack only makes use of the client area of its parent (i.e., a single screen), while the other containers provide as much room for their children as they want (because they allow scrolling).

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your MessageView in a ScrollView.